# Is it possible that entropy generation decreases with decreasing turbine efficiency(First Low efficiency )?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, turbines, cfd

I simulated an axial turbine(Wells turbine). Now I have faced with strange problem.

Performance of any turbine can be improved if the losses are identified and minimized. Several losses can be defined by flow separation, small or large vortices creation or flow circulation, etc.

In fact, when the turbine have lower efficiency than others turbines, it means that this turbine have more losses than others. In other words, the mentioned turbine have more flow separation, vortices or flow circulation than others. This again means that mentioned turbine have more entropy generation than others because entropy generation include velocity gradient terms and when separation and circulation(losses) increase, entropy generation also increases. Is my statement right?am i right?

Now, i designed an improved blade and a thicker blade(constant cord) than to base blade. . My results show that the Improved blade have better efficiency and lower entropy generation than to base blade. These results are logical. the thicker blade have lower efficiency and more losses than base blade(thinner blade) . And so, this cause higher entropy generation. But according to my results,  the thicker blade have lower efficiency(it is logical) and lower entropy generation(I think that it is not logical) than to base blade. **Is it possible that entropy generation decreases  with decreasing efficiency?**

I am grateful that guide me about this case.